# Python reactive KafkaProducer not working on Threadpool

Tags: python, threadpool, reactive-programming, kafka-producer-api

I have the following python script. When I execute it, no messages are being sent to Kafka. If the `.subscribe_on(pool_scheduler) \` line is not used, All my messages are sent to Kafka And I'm able to consume from `mytopic` in another script.

```
import multiprocessing
import json
from rx import Observable, Observer
from rx.concurrency import ThreadPoolScheduler
from kafka import KafkaProducer

class KafkaObserver(Observer):
    def __init__(self, host, port, topic):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(
                    bootstrap_servers='{}:{}'.format(host, port),
                    value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))
        self.topic = topic

    def on_next(self, value):
        print("Write point to Kafka: {0}".format(value))
        self.kafka_producer.send(self.topic, value=value)

    def on_completed(self):
        print("KafkaObserver completed!")

    def on_error(self, error):
        print("Error occured in KafkaObserver: {0}".format(error))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    kafkaobserver = KafkaObserver(
                'localhost',
                9092,
                'mytopic'
                )
    inputdata = [.....] // list of data to process
    optimal_thread_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    pool_scheduler = ThreadPoolScheduler(optimal_thread_count)
    kafka_obs = Observable.from_(inputdata) \
                          .subscribe_on(pool_scheduler) \
                          .subscribe(kafkaobserver)
```

I created some other Observers, to write to a database, and they are sending all the data the datastore, with or without the ThreadPoolScheduler.